# Access Individual Row Template in GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, templates, gridview

I have a `ListBox` (named ListBoxProperty) and `button` (btnDeselectAll) in a `TemplateField` on a `gridview` control that shows on every row of the `gridview`. The code shown below is the code behind the button control in the `TemplateField`.  This code works on every `ListBox` on every row in the `gridview`.  I would like it to only affect the `ListBox` in the gridview row from which it was clicked. I've tried a few things with failure so I didn't include my failings - just the portion that almost gives me what I want.  Couldn't include a pic alas my reputation is weak.

```
Protected Sub btnDeselectAll_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    For Each Row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim myListBox As ListBox = _
            CType(Row.FindControl("ListBoxProperty"), ListBox)
        For Each selectedItem As ListItem In myListBox.Items
            selectedItem.Selected = False
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NamingContainer` of the button is the `GridViewRow`, there you are.

```
Protected Sub btnDeselectAll_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim row = DirectCast(btn.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    Dim myListBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("ListBoxProperty"), ListBox)
    For Each selectedItem As ListItem In myListBox.Items
        selectedItem.Selected = False
    Next
End Sub
```